# Matlab remove empty cells from within cell array

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array that shows up like this

```
lists = 

    {240x1 cell}    {240x1 cell}
```

it contains letter strings, NOT numbers.

Only 200 of cells have actual content, so I need to truncate the cells getting rid of empty ones.

Now, `lists(cellfun('isempty',lists)) = [];` does not work, nor does it work with `arrayfun`. Changing `'isempty'` to `@isempty` does not work either. However, if I separate each cell of lists to a cell, like this `a = lists{1}`, the `cellfun` procedure works.

Note, I am not looking for a solution for this specific case with 200 out 240 cells having content.

FWY, the lists is a subset of an array that `textscan` spits out. The problem is that some of the columns in the initial `textscan` output do have 240 content cells, so `textscan` just defaults to that length for all the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `cellfun` twice, once on `lists` and once on its elements

```
cellfun(@(x) x(~cellfun('isempty', x)), lists, 'uni', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the cells, I am assuming that you do not need to do this recursively.

```
for i = numel(list):-1:1
    list{i}(cellfun(@isempty, list{i})) = [];
end
```